# issues with pandas txt read and ploting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read values from a txt file using pandas and plotting a scatter diagram with matploitlib but i keep getting all sort of errors while trying different methods

a summery of my txt file...

```
Brain   Body         
0.37    0.117182754
73  1.349981613
70  0.925010921
0.8 0.007620352
0.15    0.001406136
50  0.419981176


from pandas import*
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read_data

dataframe = pd.read_csv('./brain_body.txt' , header = None);
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

#Training Model on data

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)


plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values, body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

with this code i et the error message below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/body_brain_prediction.py", line 9, in <module>
    x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2981, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1271, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1078, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1163, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Brain'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: `from pandas import*` is never used in your code and, in general, is very dangerous. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly assume that the data in the file is comma-separated and does not have headers. In reality, it *does* have headers and is space-separated. The right way to read your data is as follows:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('./brain_body.txt', sep=r'\s+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code and format you .txt file by putting tab spaces

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read_data

dataframe = pd.read_csv("./brain_body",delimiter="\t")
dataframe
x_values = dataframe[["Brain"]]
y_values = dataframe[["Body"]]

#Training Model on data

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)


plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values, body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `read_csv` with `header=None` pandas will assume there are no headers. You should set `header=0` which tells pandas the first line has the headers.

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) have more information